# Alignment problem with enumerate

Tags: tables, spacing, vertical-alignment, enumerate

This simple table is not working out for me. The first item in the table does not align with the others, see picture. I can not figure out why not. Thank you.

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}}
    \item c) & \item  c) & \item  c) & \item a)& \item d) & \item b) 
    \end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SE.  It's usually more helpful to post a complete minimal document rather than a code fragment. (So wrap your code in a `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}...\end{document}`.)  What you're doing here seems like a very odd use of enumeration. (And it's actually amazing that it works at all.)  So what exactly do you want to achieve? If you simply want to number cells in a table, there are better ways to do this.  If you want an "in-line" enumeration, there are also better ways to do that.

Answer (score 1):

A list naturally inserts a spacing between elements, as well as at the start and end of the list. As such, there may be different spacing above the first `\item`, between each successive `\item`s, and after the last `\item`. In your example it's better to remove all spacing inserted by the list via the `nosep` option provided by [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[nosep]
  \begin{tabular}{ *{6}{p{25mm}} }
    \item c) & \item  c) & \item  c) & \item a) & \item d) & \item b) 
  \end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}

\noindent
\setcounter{enumi}{0}%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ *{6}{>{\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi.~\ignorespaces}X} }
  c) & c) & c) & a) & d) & b)
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Another option is proposed at the end, suggesting you use another way of automating the enumeration within a tabular. Specifically, I've used [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) to ensure that the tabular width doesn't go beyond `\textwidth`, while `\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi.~` is inserted at the start of every cell. `enumi` is the counter associated with enumeration at the root level, so I'm reusing it here.

The former method has some duplication in it, as both `\item` and `&` is used to separate an item, while the later obscures the fact that you're building a list. So, perhaps both have their (dis)advantages.

Another method, perhaps more appropriate in this situation, might be to use `inline` lists; something supported since `enumitem` V3.0:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate*}[itemjoin=\hfill]
  \item c) \item  c) \item  c) \item a) \item d) \item b) 
\end{enumerate*}

\end{document}
```

You can specify how the items are joined inside an `enumerate*` - a specific inline enumeration environment. I've used `\hfill` to stretch content across the text block width.

Comment: But surely this is not an ideal method to achieve this output?

Comment: @AlanMunn: It surely isn't.

Comment: So then you're encouraging bad practices... Isn't this what the site is trying to avoid.  Do I need to downvote you? :)  This is a classic XY problem (hence my comment to the OP).

Comment: @AlanMunn: Let me clarify. Surely there are better ways of doing it, all depending on the OP's intent. I've added another option for automated listing within (say) `tabularx`, together with some clarification as to the different methods. I don't think the OP's usage is bad *per se*, just odd.